# Must take online Maths Courses

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I have quite a long holiday this year to myself, so I've decided to work on improving my math. So, could you please recommend some nice online courses to me.

Thanks in advance, and please keep in mind that I'm 13, so some basic Maths courses should do!

Comment: Have you looked at the khan academy website?

Comment: I did take a look at that, and I have took quite a few subjects from there and well, it was quite easy that way, and I'm hoping to do a rather better, and more College-like course, you know, like, for example, the CS50x for computer science.

Comment: Calculus is a college course. I'm pretty sure Khan Academy covers it.

Comment: @Tyler: I can't really condone sending students to KA for independent learning. There is a lot of really valid criticism of the site among the math (teachers') twitter-blogosphere. As a reference I think it's fine, as a learning tool not so much.

Answer (score 1):

In my last few years of high school, I used MIT Open Courseware to study multivariable calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra. I was using them pretty seriously, i.e. I would print out the exams and give them to a teacher at the beginning of a semester and when I had done enough of the homework, they would proctor the exam for me. If that's not what you want then you can take this with a grain of salt.

Nevertheless, I felt like I learned pretty well from them, and I enjoyed it quite a bit. Of course, you shouldn't be hopping into a DEs course because that's only going to make you frustrated or quit, but they do have some courses and syllabi which at least seem like they are at a more basic level (although I stress *more* basic: these are all courses which were taught at one point to MIT students…).

Here are the four I can see, in order of how much I recommend:

- Mathematics for computer science (18.062J)
- Single-variable calculus (18.01)
- Linear algebra (18.06)
- Introduction to probability and statistics (18.05) [at least the probability part]

My main advice would be this: No matter what service you use, it will be way easier to learn if there are videos. I was always the kid who just learned things from books in middle school and high school, but when I took those courses I *really* appreciated having somebody talking it through to me. Keep in mind I haven't actually taken these classes from MIT OCW, but from my college, so any or all of them may not be any good— but I would bet that at least one of them is.